# Set a default value for kotlin generics

Tags: generics, kotlin

I have this extension function:

```
fun <T : View> Activity.bind(idRes: Int): Lazy<T> = lazy { findViewById<T>(idRes) }
```

as you can see my generic `T` should be `View` or a descendant.

whenever I want to use it to get a View descendant I do one of the following options:

```
val textView1 by bind<TextView>(R.id.text_view_1)
val textView2: TextView by bind(R.id.text_view_2)
```

pretty nice, but lets us see the problem now, sometimes I don't need the specific type, I just need View, for example when I want to set a click listener, so I have to do this:

```
val view1 by bind<View>(R.id.view_1)
val view2: View by bind(R.id.view_2)
```

I'm wondering a way to remove the explicitly type `View`, to make the kotlin compiler see it is the default once I defined `T : View`, is it possible?

In other words I want this:

```
val textView1 by bind<TextView>(R.id.text_view_1)
val textView2: TextView by bind(R.id.text_view_2)
val view by bind(R.id.view_xyz) // kotlin compiler understands it is a View
```

I did try it:

```
fun Activity.bind(idRes: Int): Lazy<View> = lazy { findViewById<View>(idRes) }

fun <T : View> Activity.bind(idRes: Int): Lazy<T> = lazy { findViewById<T>(idRes) }
```

but I got:

```
Platform declaration clash: The following declarations have the same JVM signature
```

What does make sense because of the generic type erasure…

I'm wondering for a solution that doesn't involve another method like `fun Activity.bindView...` because I want to keep the API as simple as possible.

P.S. The `synthetic` option has several bugs and it is the reason we are using this lazy bind is to move away from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kotlin compiler will always infer the most specific generic type, and there is no such thing as "default" type parameter, so you have to create extra function. You may use `JvmName` annotation to resolve the platform declaration crash:

```
fun <T> foo(): T? = null

@JvmName("foo0")
fun foo(): Any? = null

fun main() {
    foo<Nothing>()
    foo()
}
```

Comment: It does work with the usage `val textView1 by bind<TextView>(R.id.text_view_1)` but it doesn't work with the usage `val textView2: TextView by bind(R.id.text_view_2)`. Anyway, I think it solves the problem, I'm impressed with the trick :). The bind is now: `@JvmName("bindView")
fun Activity.bind(idRes: Int): Lazy<View> = lazy { findViewById<View>(idRes) }

fun <T : View> Activity.bind(idRes: Int): Lazy<T> = lazy { findViewById<T>(idRes) }`